# Difference between "from a distance" and "from the distance"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Consider these two phrases:

> "from **a** distance"
>   "from **the** distance"

Is there a difference in these two terms? When would you use which?

Answer (score 2):

**A distance** means very far away.

**The distance** generally refers to as far away as you can see IMO (some people might disagree on exactly where *"the distance"* is).

So if you say, **"He came from a distance."** It means he came from somewhere far away. A more natural way to word that would be, **"He came from quite a distance."**

On the other hand, if you say **"He came from the distance."** That means that he came from just about as far as you can see (also implying you could see him). Perhaps a better way to word the same situation would be, **"He appeared in the distance."**

Comment: It might be worth noting that “from a distance” is a fairly common and established phrase, while “from the distance” sounds a little awkward outside of certain specialized contexts, such as: *We can determine the elevation from the distance between the two points.*